# Is my code susceptible to SQL injection attack?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sql-injection, tweepy

I am a newbie to both python and sqlite, hence I need some expert or friendly advice on this. I am trying to capture tweets using Tweepy and store it in a SQLite database. Following is the code

```
stat = status.text
stat = stat.replace('\n','')
stat = stat.replace('\t','')
user_id = status.user.id_str
stat_id = status.id_str
create = str(status.created_at)
name = status.user.screen_name
data = (create, name, user_id, stat_id, stat)

c.execute("INSERT INTO tweetscapture (Date, ScreenName, UserID, TweetID, Text) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", data)
```

Can someone please verify if it is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. The only data entry source into my database is twitter.

Comment: this isn't enough information, how are the variables in data created? where does the information come from and how?

Comment: @JamesKent Isn't this really just a question about whether `c.execute()` substitutes the parameters into the prepared statement safely? Why does it matter where the information came from?

Comment: As stated in the linked question, using parameterized queries with `cursor.execute()` protects you from SQL injection.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much. I saw the other post earlier but just wasn't sure. It seems my code is safe.

Comment: @Barmar true, my bad